# Time Slot SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query to see if an engineer visited his job in a agreed time slot.

[Table Screenshot http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/1156/capturebcn.jpg](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/1156/capturebcn.jpg)

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  v.[VISITDATE], 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.[STARTTIME], 105) AS 'Startdate', 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.[STARTTIME], 108) AS 'StartTime', 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, v.[bookeddate], 105) AS 'BookedDate', 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.[starttime], 108) AS 'TimeSlotStart', 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.[endtime], 108) AS 'TimeSlotEnd',
  v.[Status]        
FROM
  [tbl_repair_visit] v 
  INNER JOIN [ltbl_TimeSlots] t ON v.timeslot = t.[Slot]
```

The `'StartDate'` and `'StartTime'` is the date and time the engineer went.

`'BookedDate'` is the date he should have gone, and `'TimeSlotStart'` and `'TimeSlotEnd'` defines the time span in which he should have started working. So I need a column that is a True/False value to say if he went in the correct time or not.

Comment: Do you mean agreed date as well as agreed timeslot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN StartDate = BookedDate AND StartTime BETWEEN TimeSlotStart and TimeSlotEnd
            THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
    END
FROM
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
WHERE Startdate = BookedDate AND StartTime <= TimeSlotEnd AND StartTime >= TimeSlotStart
```

?